# Remove released module by official way

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a Go module which was published (using go modules) and I want to remove it because it was a "bad" release.

So how can I remove my released module use official way?

Comment: What do you mean by "official"?

Answer (score 2):

According official documentation you have to use [`retract`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-retract) directive.